# How do I output a string from a void function?

Tags: c++, function, void

I have made a void function and am currently attempting to output the results from passing a string variable through it, but this error occurs and I'm not sure what it is implying.  I have used this code to output void functions in the past, so I'm not sure why this one is different.  Below, on the line that's within the if loop, is the line that is the source of the error.

```
if(choice == 'r')
    {
        cout << "Edited text: " << replaceExclamation(a) << endl;

    }



void replaceExclamation(string usrStr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < usrStr.length(); ++i )
    {
        if(usrStr.at(i) == '!')
        {
            usrStr.insert(i, ".");

        }
    }

}
```

///
     The error reads: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and 'void')

Comment: The error is implying that you are trying to use a return value of a function that does not in fact return any. Why again don't you make it return a value? At the moment, it's an elaborate no-op.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And you can't have used that to "output void functions in the past" as that's simply not valid. If you had it working, then either your compiler was very flawed and wrong, or there was something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

`void` means the function does not return any value.

Therefore, `cout << "Edited text: " << replaceExclamation(a) << endl;` is wrong.

To write like this, you have to change the function to return a `string` value.

```
string replaceExclamation(string usrStr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < usrStr.length(); ++i )
    {
        if(usrStr.at(i) == '!')
        {
            usrStr.insert(i, ".");

        }
    }
    return usrStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the modification is applied to a local variable and it will not be reflected in the main. Use pass by reference like so:

```
if(choice == 'r')
    {
        replaceExclamation(a); // Allow the variable to be modified before printing
        cout << "Edited text: " << a << endl;
    }
```

And

```
void replaceExclamation(string& usrStr ) // Pass parameter by reference
{
    for(int i = 0; i < usrStr.length(); ++i )
    {
        if(usrStr.at(i) == '!')
        {
            usrStr.insert(i, ".");    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't thanked you sooner.  I thought about what you said and it makes sense. The algorithm had to modify the string before I could output it.  Silly mistake.  Thank you again.